# opencv camera is noisy on the darkness

Tags: android, opencv, camera

I'm using `opencv4android 3.2`, I see that the camera is not too clear, it's noisy, I developed before an application using camera hardware, and it's clear, check the difference between those two images [image: hardwar.camera] [image: opencv camera]

I'm using the same preview size, why the camera of opencv is not clear enough?
PS: for the first screenshot (using hardware) camera I can scan the barcode but on the second (using OpenCV camera on darkness) I can't scan the barcode, I need more brightness.

```
  public abstract class CameraBridgeViewBase extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {


 @Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    final int width = resolveSize(getSuggestedMinimumWidth(), widthMeasureSpec);
    final int height = resolveSize(getSuggestedMinimumHeight(), heightMeasureSpec);
    setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
    Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
    if (camera != null && parameters.getSupportedPreviewSizes() != null) {
        Camera.Size size = getOptimalPreviewSize(parameters.getSupportedPreviewSizes(), width, height);
        parameters.setPreviewSize(size.width, size.height);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think I am getting blind or something, but I do not see any bar code in any of the two images?

Comment: thanks for your comment @api55 , i'm just post the images to see the diference between the two cameras